# Accessing variables in public constructor in java

Tags: java

If you have

```
class Triangle
{
  private double x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
  public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) 
  { 
    x1=point1.getX();
    y1=point1.getY();
    x2=point2.getX();
    y2=point2.getY();
    x3=point3.getX();
    y3=point3.getY();

    //Trying to get x and y values of point1-point3

  }

  double width=x1-x2;
  double length=y3-y2;

  public double area() 
  { 
    return (length * width)/2; 
  }
}
```

EDIT: I'm also only getting values for everything but length. length prints out 0 but y3 and y2 are still able to print values. I'm using a random number generator for doubles:

```
double randomValue = Math.random() * 100;
```

Could this be an issue with subtraction for doubles?

I basically have points defined to take two variables x and y and I'm trying to calculate this area of a triangle. When someone gives 3 points to make this triangle, I'm trying to get those values from the points and I do have getters for my points but I'm just ending up with nothing for length and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
double width=x1-x2;
double length=y3-y2;
```

Should be in your constructor.

As is it now, it is executed prior to the constructor, when x1,x2,y3,y2 are still 0.

```
  double width;
  double length;

  public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) 
  { 
    x1=point1.getX();
    y1=point1.getY();
    x2=point2.getX();
    y2=point2.getY();
    x3=point3.getX();
    y3=point3.getY();

    // init width and length after x1,x2,y3,y2 are intialized
    width=x1-x2;
    length=y3-y2;
  }
```

The alternative is to calculate `width` and `length` only when you need them :

```
  public double area() 
  { 
    double width=x1-x2;
    double length=y3-y2;
    return (length * width)/2; 
  }
```

Comment: @jacobohunter Sorry, that was a typo. I meant they should be only initialized in the constructor. They should be declared outside it.

Comment: Yeah I was to able to implement that but still get nothing for my length value, I edited and showed how I calculate my values for my points with a random double generator, could that be an issue? Because I get values for everything except length, it's not liking to subtract the y values

Comment: @jacobohunter First of all, 3 random points don't necessarily make a triangle (the can be on the same line)). Second of all, your formula is not correct for general triangles. It assumes that y1=y2 for the calculation of length and height. length should be the distance between p1 and p2 and height the distance between the line (p1,p2) and the point p3.

Comment: Goodpoint I know 3 random points don't necessarily make a triangle but I don't really know how to do it otherwise and this is supposed to be a basic java program tutorial. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @jacobohunter If you want your code to work, you must make assumption on the input. y1 must be equal to y2. Otherwise, you have to use a different formula (for example, width would be sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2), length is more complicated - you should Google the correct formula).

Comment: I know what you're saying but I don't see how that would effect the values of length. I know what you're saying makes sense if I want it to be an actual triangle but that doesn't really matter if I can't seem to subtract two doubles, i can even add but just not subtract when calculating length.

Comment: @jacobohunter Can you print the actual coordinates of the points passed to the constructor?

Comment: Yes hold on, and it works if I give the coordinates with plain integer values just not double values.

Comment: @jacobohunter Is the Point class you are using java.awt.Point? That class stores x and y as int.

Comment: No I created my own point class that takes two integers x and y. I just found out that my random double was the same... 36.38625177232663
36.38625177232663
36.38625177232663 so I figured it out haha, thanks anyway through troubleshooting

Answer (score 3):

`width` and `length` should both be local variables inside of your `area()` method or inside of your constructor. It can be calculated in your constructor if this object is immutable, but I would say it is best to calculate them in the `area()` method if you expose getters/setters to the objects.

```
public double area() 
{ 
    double width=x1-x2;
    double length=y3-y2;
    return (length * width)/2;
}
```

As you have it right now, they are [package private members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of your class, and are being set when you instantiate the class.

Comment: +1: Yep, better to calculate them when needed, in case they change after having been passed into the constructor.

Comment: I still get 0 for my value, like I said for some reason when I try to print length, it returns 0, but I'm able to get values for width and y3 and y2